# C# Passing Values between dependent Comboboxes

Tags: c#, combobox, oledb

I'm relatively new but I've been researching this issue for over 2 days, so I think I've done my due diligence ... however if this has already been answered before I apologize.
  My basic issue is I'm trying to create some dependent combo boxes.  The wrinkle is the displayed value is typically not the lookup value for the next query/Combo box (I'm using an OLEDB compliant data base)
  For example: Table1 (T1) contains ID (int) & NM (string), Table2 (T2) contains ID (int) & STATUS (string).  I run Query1 (Q1) to display T1.NM in Combobox1 (CB1),  when selected I run Query1a to lookup/get the selected Table1.ID to pass to Query2 that populates Combobox2.  The connection string and Q1 work fine, CB1 displays properly, but once I select this error is thrown:
  "OleDbException .. SQL Passthru expression ... using equals (=) has components that are of different data types"

// ** Initial connection & populate CB1 - This works fine **

```
public void comboboxLoad()
      {
            string conn3str = <Connection String >;
            string query1 = "select NM from Table1 where REFVALUE=1 ; ";
            OleDbConnection conn3 = new OleDbConnection(conn3str);
            OleDbCommand tblRow1 = new OleDbCommand(query1, conn3);
            OleDbDataReader rdRow1;
            try
            {
                conn3.Open();
                lblConnState.Text = "Connection Successful";
                rdRow1 = tblRow1.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdRow1.Read())
                {
                    int colindx1 = rdRow1.GetOrdinal("NM");
                    string sItbl = rdRow1.GetString(colindx1);
                    CB1.Items.Add(sItbl);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error  " + ex);
            }
        }
```

// ** Get value from CB1, create query to populate CB2 **

```
private void CB1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string conn3str = <Connection String >;
            OleDbConnection conn3 = new OleDbConnection(conn3str); 
            conn3.Open();

            // Pass the selected value from CB1 (string) equal to Table1.NM (string)           
            string query1a = "select ID from Table1 where NM = '" + CB1.Text + "' ; ";
            OleDbCommand TabID = new OleDbCommand(query1a, conn3);
            int TabId2 = Convert.ToInt32(TabID.ExecuteScalar());
            // Pass the variable TabId2 (int) equal to Table2.ID (int)                       
            string query2 = "select STATUS from Table2 where ID = '" + TabId2 + "'; ";

            OleDbCommand tblRow2 = new OleDbCommand(query2, conn3);
            // OleDbDataReader rdTabID;
            // OleDbDataReader rdRow2;

            try
            {
                OleDbDataReader rdRow2 = TabID.ExecuteReader();
                OleDbDataReader rdTabID = tblRow2.ExecuteReader(); // ** Error points to this line **

                while (rdRow2.Read())
                {
                    int TabIdidx = rdTabID.GetOrdinal("ID");
                    string TabIDVal = rdTabID.GetString(TabIdidx);
// Pass reference ID to label on form
                    lblBTableID.Text = TabId2.ToString();

                    int colindx1 = rdRow2.GetOrdinal("STATUS"); 
                    string sIntVal = rdRow2.GetString(colindx1);
                    cmbLowLvl.Items.Add(sIntVal);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error  " + ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: use the debugger and step through your own code initially setting break points also it would help if you tell us what line in your code that's throwing the error and or failing..

Answer (score 0):

Are you positive you're getting a value back on this line `int TabId2 = Convert.ToInt32(TabID.ExecuteScalar());`?

`Convert.ToInt32` doesn't throw a `ArgumentNullException` like  `int.Parse` does so it's possible that the variable is not getting set.

Also you may want to consider changing your queries to use parameterized SQL rather than concatenation for security purposes. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I've narrowed down the problem to the second query, the text value in the where statement isn't properly formatted.  The first query worked because the where statement was an int variable and the comparison value was hardcoded, i.e. where REFVALUE=1.

Comment: Sorry, hit enter by mistake.  I've tried every variation of " & ' & + but no joy.  My OLEDB interface doesn't support  ICommandWithParameters .

Comment: Try removing the single ticks from around the variable: `string query2 = "select STATUS from Table2 where ID = " + TabId2 + "; ";`. If that doesn't work have you verified that if you hardcode the second query it doesn't error out just to make sure we're chasing the correct  error?

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to figure out the problem.  I'm really not sure why it didn't work originally, but I think it was a reader mismatch, since I was only looking for a single value back from the query ExecuteScalar() seemed to do the trick and I didn't need the 'while' loop.  The working code is below.
  Next I'll need to pass this return value (ID) in my next query to populate CB2.  Thanks @

```
private void CB1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string conn3str = <Connection String >;
        OleDbConnection conn3 = new OleDbConnection(conn3str); 


        // Pass the selected value from CB1 (string) equal to Table1.NM (string) but return the int ID.

    OleDbCommand tblRow2 = new OleDbCommand("select ID from Table1 where NM=  '"+ CB1.Text +"' ;" , conn3);
    try
        {
        conn3.Open();
                string r2 = Convert.ToString(tblRow2.ExecuteScalar());
                MessageBox.Show(r2);
                lblBTableID.Text = "ID Code= " + r2;
                conn3.Close();
    }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error  " + ex);
        }
    }
```